# Use Wagtail CMS Snippets but Hide in Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I am building custom AdminModels based on Wagtail Snippets and have a custom menu in the AdminPanel for my models.  How do I hide/remove the Snippet selection from AdminPanel without disabling?  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can u please put some code .. and my suggestion is to remove admin.site.register() which u want to remove

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following hook into wagtail_hooks.py file of your Wagtail CMS app:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore import hooks

@hooks.register('construct_main_menu')
def hide_snippets_menu_item(request, menu_items):
  menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'snippets']
```

And you're basically done! You can use this approach to hide any item from the admin menu.

I described it recently on my blog: http://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-remove-snippets-menu-item-from-wagtail-cms-admin-menu/

Comment: Awesome! Thank You.

Answer (score 8):

Since `item.name` in `menu_items` can be blank, better solution is:

```python
from wagtail.snippets.wagtail_hooks import SnippetsMenuItem

@hooks.register('construct_main_menu')
def hide_snippets_menu_item(request, menu_items):
    menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if not isinstance(item, SnippetsMenuItem)]
```

Comment: I had an issue using the accepted answer because we use multiple names, depending on the user's language.. This solution is actually better